# Question about how to pass a parameter within a dapper query call

Tags: c#, dapper

```
class Foo1
{ 
    protected const string _SQL1 = "SELECT UnitID, Name FROM Table1;";

    internal static List<Foo2> XTable1;

    public Foo1()
    {
        try  
        {
            using (IDbConnection _cnnDB = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectDBString()))
            { 
                XTable1 = _cnnDB.Query<Foo2>(_SQL1).AsList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e); 
        }
    }
}

class Foo2
{
    protected const string _SQL2 = "SELECT Name FROM Table2 WHERE InitID = @XUnitId;";

    internal static List<Foo2> XTable1;

    internal string _Name;
    internal int16 _ID;

    Public Foo2()
    {
        try 
        {
            using (IDbConnection _cnnDB = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectDBString()))
            { 
                XTable2 = _cnnDB.Query<Foo3>(_SQL2).AsList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e); 
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name;
    }

    public string UnitID
    {
        get => _ID;
    }
}

class Foo3
{
    internal string _Name;

    Public Foo3
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _Name;
    }
}

static class MyMain
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
       Foo1 theFoo = new Foo1();
    }
}
```

I am learning the connections between Dapper and C#.  I want to be able to have an internal list of sub classes  defined within the parent class.  I would like to have the subclass just have the data that is defined by the parent class that created it.  I am sorry I still have not learned all the correct terms for what I am doing.
I need help trying to figure how to get a parameter out of the select statement in foo1 and passed to foo2.  I have tried the 'new' command inside the Query command but it seems that the data is not available when the Query is running.  Can anyone point me to where I am not seeing the correct way to code this?

I have cleaned up the code and it compiles now.

Comment: Calling into SQL inside a constructor sounds like the epitome of bad design. It's also subject to the N+1 problem (for every row of one query, another query is fired). Perhaps consider using `QueryMultiple` or multi-mapping to get back multiple different sets of data and map it into the objects.

Answer (score 0):

If the thing you want as `@XUnitId` is the value from `_ID`, then:

```
XTable2 = _cnnDB.Query<Foo3>(_SQL2, new { XUnitId = _ID }).AsList();
```

Comment: Am I coding this wrong because when I debug it _ID is always null but if I let it run _ID has a number when the code completes but no foo3 is created.  There are records for the  _SQL2 to return if XUnitId has a value.

Comment: @Tim well, the code as presented is impossible for me to comment on, as it is inherently broken; `int16` doesn't exist (`Int16` does), and at one point it is unclear whether it is a `string` or that or something else. An `Int16` is never null - it literally cannot be null

Comment: However, you might want to look for when you assign it a non-zero value. I can't see that either.

Comment: i am going to clean up the code and try again

Comment: @Tim happy to try and help more, but real code that compiles (and possibly even runs, even if it doesn't give the result you wanted) helps a lot, for the external reader

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out what was not working for me by removing the static keyword from all my lists.  I was able to put just the items I wanted into each list.  I also moved my creation of nested classes out of the constructor into its own method so it would only fire when I called it.

The answer to the title questions is indeed to use the command that Marc provided.

```
XTable2 = _cnnDB.Query<Foo3>(_SQL2, new { XUnitId = _ID }).AsList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).